# How to add link to my module in the Structure admin page

Tags: 7, users, files

I would like to add a link to my module in the Structure admin page.

I already use a hook_menu for turn in my module accessible but how can I add a link in the "structure" admin section ?

`function tamtamimporter_modules_menu() {
$items['admin/config/tamtamimporter'] = array(
        'title' => 'Gestion du Tamtam importer',
        'description' => 'Gestion de l\'importation des flux par le biais du module Tamtam importer',
        'page callback' => 'tamtamimporter_modules_page',
        'page arguments' => array('tamtamimporter_modules_page'),
        'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
        'file' => 'tamtamimporter_modules.admin_list.inc',
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
}`

Thank you very much for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it currently appearing under config? I think all you need to do is change the path to being 'admin/structure/mylinkgoeshere' and a link will appear under structure

Answer (score 1):

You would need to specify a url that beggins with `/admin/structure` for that matter (Drupal 7).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet from simplenews module which shows implementation of hook_menu using multiple links

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function simplenews_menu() {
  $items['admin/content/simplenews'] = array(
    'title' => 'Newsletters',
    'description' => 'List newsletters and newsletter sent status.',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('simplenews_admin_newsletter_issues'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer newsletters'),
    'file' => 'includes/simplenews.admin.inc',
  );
  $items['admin/config/services/simplenews'] = array(
    'title' => 'Newsletters',
    'description' => 'Configure your sites newsletters.',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('simplenews_admin_categories'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer newsletters'),
    'file' => 'includes/simplenews.admin.inc',
  );


  $items['admin/config/services/simplenews/categories'] = array(
    'title' => 'Newsletters',
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
  );

  .......


  return $items;
}
```

It clearly shows that  you can do your work with

```
$items['admin/structure']=....
```

Comment: Which part of that code has anything to do with placing a link under admin/structure?

Comment: I think his primary issue is adding another link as he already added one so from above answer it is very simple to do
just provide value for $items['admin/structure']=...

Comment: That isn't what he asked, though..

Comment: might I misunderstood, edited my answer :)